# Replace values in an array or list continuously

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am very new to coding and I was wondering if it is possible to limit an array in python to 100 items.

If it is possible, can you keep adding to that array and pushing out the old numbers in the array? So the oldest number should be pushed out to make room each time a new number is added.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about creating a simple function to do this:

```
def add_to_array(lst, item, maxsize):

    if len(lst) >= maxsize:
        lst.pop(0)

    lst.append(item)
```

Which works like this:

```
>>> lst = [i for i in range(1, 10)]
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> add_to_array(lst, 10, 10)
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> add_to_array(lst, 11, 10)
>>> lst
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

**Note:** If your looking for something more efficient, you can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque), as pointed out in the other answer.

Here is an example of using `deque` to emulate your desired behaviour:

```
>>> lst = deque((i for i in range(1, 10)), maxlen=10)
>>> lst
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], maxlen=10)
>>> lst.append(10)
>>> lst
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], maxlen=10)
>>> lst.append(11)
>>> lst
deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], maxlen=10)
```

Comment: Worth pointing out: given the purpose of a queue of fixed length is to `append` and `pop` I think the performance benefit of `deque` over `list` type may be important.

Comment: This does sort of the opposite of what the asker wants - the *newest* entry is kicked out when adding more instead of the *oldest*. `lst.pop(0)` is probably what you want. But actually, as @jp_data_analysis shows, really what they probably want is `deque`.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis point noted. Worth pointing out also: the OP is new to coding and is probably looking for something simple like this. Having said that, this is definitely less efficient, but I don't think at this point that should be a problem for the OP.

Comment: Considering OP didn't know to ask about `deque` or `queue` or specify `FIFO`, I think it's safe to assume that performance won't be a concern here :-)

Comment: @RoadRunner. It's a good idea to introduce both the existing tools and the *techniques* to reinvent the wheel. That being said, `lst.append(item)` should probably not appear twice in the `if` statement. You can flip the condition, remove the `else`, and move it out entirely.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Updated answer.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it's possible via [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

lst = deque([], 100)
```

Like `list.append`, `deque.append` works in place:

```
A = deque(range(10), maxlen=10)

print(A)

deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], maxlen=10)

A.append(10)

print(A)

deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], maxlen=10)
```

Comment: With `lst.append(xxx)`.